# Copy in contenteditable <span>

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable

I need to copy content in span tag `<span contenteditable="true">//content</span>`
but it is not implemented in FireFox, is there any solutions for this?
and this is my span http://jsfiddle.net/watxD/

Comment: Do you mean you want to copy to the system clipboard? If so, there's no way without getting the user to change a Firefox setting.

Comment: @TimDow can you tell me which setting exactly need to change

Answer (score 1):

A. `var Result = $('span[contenteditable="true"]').text();`

B. `var Result = $('span[contenteditable="true"]').html();`

C. List of nodes inside: `var Result = $('span[contenteditable="true"]').contents();`

D. You can do it with Rangy Library http://code.google.com/p/rangy/. (It use native methods for FF, Chrome, Opera, IE9 and not-native for IE <= 8 )
Code below is using jQuery - but you can rewrite it on pure node Javascript

1. You need to create range for you node

   ```
   var Range = rangy.createRange();
   ```
2. You need to select content of node

   ```
   Range.selectNodeContents( $('span[contenteditable="true"]')[0] )
   ```
3. Represent result as you want:

   ```
   var Result = Range.toString(); // Returns the text contained within the range.

   var Result = Range.toHtml(); // Returns a string containing an HTML representation of the range.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't pure JavaScript way to do this in Firefox without requiring the user to mess around with their preferences. Allowing general access to the system clipboard from JavaScript is dangerous, so the user may not want to do this. Here's an article that outlines the issues and how to enable clipboard access in Firefox. I don't know whether it's up to date.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard

The other option is a Flash-based hacky workaround such as [ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/).